# Fire onChange event on input type number with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have input with type number:

```
<input type="number" id="input-number" onChange="DoSomething();"/>
```

How to fire onChange event with jQuery?

[EDIT]

Did it with following code:

```
$("#input_0").trigger("change");
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Fire'? Do you want jQuery to trigger the event, i.e. make an event, where there is no user event; or do you want to react on a user event?

Answer (score -1):

With [`trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> Any event handlers attached with `.on()` or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the `.trigger()` method. A call to `.trigger()` executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user:

```js
console.clear()
DoSomething = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target)
}

$('#input-number').trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" id="input-number" onChange="DoSomething(event);"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look attached example.

You need to setup the jquery function `($(selector).change())` which is fired when lost the focus from textbox.

```js
$("#input-number").on('change',function(){
  alert($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input-number"/>
```

Comment: OP is asking how to *fire* a change event, not *listen* for a change event